# Select a random row with where statement is taking to long

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select a random row with a specific where statement but the query is taking to long (around 2.7 seconds)

```
SELECT * FROM PIN WHERE available = '1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

The database contains around 900k rows

Thanks

Comment: have you an index  on available  ?? and if you have the index is this column really selective??  remember that the limit 1 is applied  on the full result of the query

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast

Comment: RAND() is a bit slow, I'm afraid. Not a lot you can do about that

Comment: Also see http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: ...or https://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM PIN WHERE available = '1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

means, that you are going to generate a random number for EVERY row, then sort the whole result-set and finally retrieve one row.

That's a lot of work for querying a single row.

Assuming you have id's without gaps - or only little of them - you better use the programming language you are using to generate ONE random number - and fetch that id:

Pseudo-Example:

```
result = null;
min_id = queryMinId();
max_id = queryMaxId();
while (result == null){
  random_number = random_beetween(min_id, max_id);

  result = queryById(randomNumber);
}
```

If you have a lot of gaps, you could retrieve the whole id-set, and then pick ONE random number from that result prior:

```
id_set = queryAllIds();
random_number = random_beetween(0, size(id_set)-1);

result = queryById(id_set[random_number])
```

---

The first example will work without additional constraints. In your case, you should use option 2. This ensures, that all IDs with `available=1` are pre-selected into an `0` to `count() -1` array, hence ignoring all invalid ids.

Then you can generate a random number between `0` and `count() -1` to get an `index` within that result-set, which you can translate to an actual ID, which you are going to fetch finally.

```
id_set = queryAllIdsWithAvailableEqualsOne(); //"Condition"
random_number = random_beetween(0, size(id_set)-1);

result = queryById(id_set[random_number])
```